# How to select the next element with same class?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My question is formed by two parts:

1. How to select the next element with the same class and hide the previous one?
2. How can I add in each input hidden value, the value of button that is pressed? Let's say I press the button with class 'no'. I want the 'no' to go in it's input hidden value of the question. How to do that?

Thank you so much. Any kind of help would be kindly appreciated.

This is what I have so far:

HTML:

```js
$('.answer_buttons a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected').hide().next().show().addClass('selected');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '',
        data: {},
        success: function(msj){
            //alert('test');
            //console.log(msj);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <input name="intr1" value="" type="hidden">
  <p class="question selected" id="intreb_1">
    Intrebarea 1?</p>
  <input name="intr2" value="" type="hidden">
  <p class="question " id="intreb_2">
    Intrebarea 2?</p>
  <input name="intr3" value="" type="hidden">
  <p class="question " id="intreb_3">
    Intrebarea 3?</p>
  <input name="intr4" value="" type="hidden">
  <p class="question " id="intreb_4">
    Intrebarea 4?</p>
  <input name="intr5" value="" type="hidden">
  <p class="question " id="intreb_5">
    Intrebarea 5?</p>
  <div class="answer_buttons">
    <a class="nu" href=""></a>
    <a class="da" href=""></a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What you have done is right.

Comment: Write complete JS code

Comment: what you are looking for is the `nth-child` selector in jquery

Comment: @Sunil Pachlangia, I updated my question. For the first question the answer was given by Vohuman. Can anyone help me with the second question. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you want to select the next sibling `.question` of the current `.question.selected` element. For doing this you can use the `.nextAll()` and `.first()` methods:

```
$('.selected').removeClass('selected')
              .hide()
              .nextAll('.question')
              .first()
              .show()
              .addClass('selected');
```

And for updating value of the previous `input` sibling by using the `className` of the clicked element you can use the `.prev()` and `.val()` methods.

```
$('.selected')...
              .addClass('selected')
              .prev('input')
              .val($(this).hasClass('nu') ? 'no' : 'yes');
```

Comment: This works well for my first question. Thank you. Can you help me with my second question too, please.

Comment: Man, you're an angel. I tried methods that gave me headaches. This is the best answer I've seen. Thank you so much. I will accept the answer and upvote this. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ionut You are very welcome! I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: Hmm, one problem I found. The value in the first hidden input is not updated. It starts from the second one. I made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9x8co7f1/1/

Comment: @Ionut That's true. I have updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1jkv38e2/. I have used the `end` method for chaining all the methods.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you again. I didn't new that you can chain methods like that. Learned something new today.

Comment: And if i have the hidden input inside p tag how would make this to work? Sorry for asking to much. I'm just curious.

Comment: I've made it. I used find() instead of prev();